# ASP.NET OWIN vs Singleton Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm working on a Web App where I instantiated my a Singleton class below in Startup.cs in order to be reused (more like making a programmable session):

```
 app.CreatePerOwinContext<XYZManager>(XYZManager.Create);
```

But I'm encountering a problem, as soon as UserA logs in on the app, the information inside XYZManager class gets overwritten when UserB enters and vice versa when they perform some action.

The problem I think is, they're sharing the same application pool, how can this be resolve, any hack?

An meanwhile the whole essence of this approach, I want to be able to call any getter / setter of method inside XYZManager for the current logged user for example:

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<XYZManager>().GetFullDetails();
```

But sometimes throw details for another logged on user based on operations.

```
 public class XYZManager : IDisposable
 {
     private static XYZManager instance  { get; set; }
     public static  XYZManager Create()
     {
        var xyzManager = instance ?? (instance = new XYZManager());
        xyzManager.ApplicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        return xyzManager;
     }
     public string GetFullDetails () {
        return "blah blah";
     }
 }
```

Comment: I cannot see any singleton, I only see an instance created *per request* (an owin context is created on every request). Your issue is certainly caused by your `XYZManager` class design.

Comment: Thanks @FedericoDipuma I will update my questions with the XYZManager Singleton

Comment: @FedericoDipuma see my updated post, what could be wrong?

Comment: Afaik CreatePerOwinContext, will try to create a separate singleton instance each time user logs in with your provided method (Create), but instead of  creating a new one it returns the old instance.  I think you shouldn't use a singleton here.

Comment: @Ernis, what should I use?

Comment: Why your `Create` method returns the same instance in the first place? Having your `XYZManager` as a singleton just means that **any** thread/request will share its internal parameters. It's not clear at all what you want to achieve, but clearly a singleton instance for your purpose is the wrong choice.

Comment: Just return a new instance, not a singleton, and HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<XYZManager>() will return that same created instance

Comment: @Ernis, another question I kept on asking myself why is  HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager>() not returning another logged on user's UserManager?

Comment: @Ernis, I tried that but still same result, I will try again anyway...Thanks

Comment: @FedericoDipuma, I knew somebody would ask me this question. But the sorrow thing is...even without wiring-up my XYZManager with Owin, the result was still the same, I was formally using it without Owin where each users shares resources and overwrites their information on the fly

Comment: You need to create a new instance **per request** and dispose of the instance at the end of each request. There are plenty of tutorials out there on how to do this but really you should be using a DI pattern where you inject any dependencies you need into your ApiController instance(s). You should not have to create factories to create your dependencies.

Comment: BTW: If you want to set this up using an IoC container I wrote an answer a while back that uses NInject but you can substitute another framework like AutoFac. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36296270/1260204

Comment: @Igor, this is not about Dependency Injection, every design pattern has their own solution to a problem. Why I'm trying to use this, is to have a in-memory programmable session if I may explain. I know DI, and I uses Unity / SimpleInjector.

Comment: DI would solve the problem assuming you register the type as new instance per request. You are creating a singleton where there should not be one (`static XYZManager instance`). It *might* be ok if this was a windows application where the application instance was serving only a single user. For a web application though this will cause multiple run time bugs like the one you are experiencing now. You want a new instance per request, a DI framework can easily provide that for you. So I encourage you to use Unity or SimpleInjector (pick your favorite) and register the manager type that way.

Comment: *continued* ^^^------- See the previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36296270/1260204 for specifics on how to register the owin types.

Comment: @Igor I think you're making more sense, but let me give a try and get back to you on that...thanks so much.

Comment: _The problem I think is, they're sharing the same application pool_ Yes, not only are all your users sharing the same application pool. Multiple web sites may share a single application pool. Each application pool executes in a Windows process. However, every ASP.NET website in an application pool (process) will be in a separate appdomains to keep them isolated. Trying to provide a separate application pool for every user does not make any sense.

Comment: @Martin Liversage, please don't quote me wrong...I'm not trying to create separate application pool, I just want a hack to this problem, in such a way, single instance of class should be apply for one application (current session) for the current user.

Comment: @EmmanuelOsinnowo: My quote from your answer is exactly what you have written so I fail to see how it is wrong. I am just trying to provide some insight into the concept af application pools. Hacking with the application pool will not solve your problem. That is basically what I am trying to say (with some bonus information).

Comment: @MartinLiversage Thanks so much, really appreciate

Answer (score 1):

As described in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn612979%28v=vs.108%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), the `CreatePerOwinContext` method will accept a factory method to create an instance of your class (in this cas XYZManager), and it will keep it for all same context requests with.

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<XYZManager>()
```

So each time a new Owin Context is created (a new http request received) XYZManager.Create will be invoked. In your case this method returns the same instance, so all contexts will share that instance.

Depending if you want to share that instance for all contexts or not you should return new or the same instances. Also note, that for singleton shared instances there is a different Owin extension method that will keep the singleton for you.

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26627783/3046223) as it explains what is the purpose of the `CreatePerOwinContext` method, as well as provide some examples how to create a inter context shared instance.

This is how you create Context shared service

```
public class XYZManager : IDisposable
{
     public static  XYZManager Create()
     {
         return  new XYZManager(new ApplicationDbContext());
     }
     private readonly ApplicationDbContext DbContext;

     public XYZManager(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
     {
         DbContext = dbContext;
     }
     public string SomeInfo {get;set;}
     public string GetFullDetails () 
     {
         return dbContext.getFullDetails();
     }
     // dispose
 }
```

Note: Since you will be creating instances each time a new owin context is creates it is advisable, to make sure any unmanaged objects are disposed.

Comment: I will try this out and give you update in a jiffy thanks @Ernis

Comment: the result remain the same, UserA logs  on, UserB overwrite UserA's info when logged on and vice versa.

Comment: @EmmanuelOsinnowo I noticed, that your method GetUserDetails is static. Only factory method `Create` should be static, all other methods and properties should be instance methods.

Comment: let's assume it's a non-static, but though that's a mistake, that's not how it is in my source code, will update the question...my bad.

Comment: @EmmanuelOsinnowo if you are still getting overwrites, there is a problem with XYZ manager data storage class, check how your data is stored with breakpoints.

Comment: Okay @Ernis, I will and shall get back to you

Comment: I've tried it, but not working...instead there's fresh instantiation of XYZManager class